# Regular expression to match whole list as well as its parts

Tags: java, regex

In Java I have a string like `+aba,biba,-miba`, which is a list to sort orders. There might be any number of parts. "aba" "biba", "miba" are just examples.

- I would like to make a regular expression, which finds +/- and `aba`, `biba`, `miba`.
- I would also like to check if a full string matches the syntax. Which means, that I need to find `+aba,biba,-miba` as well.

I managed to write regex for the first part:

```
([+-]?)([^,]*)[,]?
```

How should I complete the expression that I can get 2nd part out of it as well?

Comment: I suggest in your case to use a simple `Split` function.

Comment: If you are searching for the exact string `+aba,biba,-miba`, why do you need a regular expression. Isn't method `equals()` good enough?

Comment: Are there always 3 parts?

Comment: String is just an example. Of course I don't search for exact string.

Comment: No, there might be any number of parts.

Comment: You could get the separate parts using `\G([+-]?)([^,]+)(?:,|$)` and then get the whole match by looping the matches and concatenate group 1 and group 2 delimited by a comma. https://regex101.com/r/g6bUR3/1 Or also capture the comma in an extra group and concat 3 groups.

Comment: @Thefourthbird I think it is another case of "validate-then-extract" thing. I already answered with a single regex once, and got downvoted heavily for that. So, here, I'd suggest a two step solution: `if (s.matches("[+-]?[^,]+(?:,[+-]?[^,]+)*")) { String[] results = s.split(","); }`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That would be much easier indeed. It is a good solution, I don't see a reason to downvote it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, if I understood well, it means that I will need separate regex for validation?

Comment: Ok, I closed with the relevant post. You will find all kinds of solutions there.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the complexity of the list, i.e. what could be part of it, a regex to check the entire list would be quite straight forward. This regex could contain a group that represents each part as well as a quantifier but you wouldn't be able to extract the all the parts from a single regex as Java's implementation isn't built that way. Thus you'd need to either use a simple `split()` to get the parts or a second regex to extract them.

Assuming your list is separated by comma, doesn't contain whitespace and only allows +/- as well as lower-case characters you could use the following expression to check the format of the list:

```
boolean listMatches = list.matches("^([+-]?[a-z]+(,(?!$))?)*$");
```

Note that `String.matches()` makes `^` and `$` superfluous but I added them for completeness in case you use another method to apply the expression. This basically checks for any number ob lower-case "names" preceded by an optional + or - and followed by a comma if it isn't the last character in the string.

Note that this would allow for a empty lists as well. If the list must contain at least one element you might use something like this:

```
boolean listMatches = list.matches("^[+-]?[a-z]+(,[+-]?[a-z]+)*$");
```

Looking for the parts could then look like this:

```
 Pattern partPattern = Pattern.compile("([+-]?)([a-z]+)");
 Matcher partMatcher = partPattern.matcher(list);
 while( partMatcher.find() ) {
    String direction = partMatcher.group(1);
    String name = partMatcher.group(2);
 }
```

Note that this could also be done with a combination of `list.split(",")`, `list.charAt(0)` and `list.subString(1,list.length())` - it's up to you :)

Comment: There is no point in using `Matcher#find` for the second step. After you validated the string, all you need is `list.split(",")`. Note you changed OP validation subpattern to only match lowercase ASCII letters, it might not work for OP.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you're right that's why I mentioned `split()` in the first paragraph. However, doing so would require some more operations to get the direction, i.e. getting the first character, checking if it is a + or - and if so getting a substring for the name.